# Entity Framework Core 6 : database update on server without sdk

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Does anyone know how to run EF6 database update on a production server where you do not want to install SDK?

In EF3 I used to call the `ef.dll` directly and that worked well.

Running `..\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\6.0.1\tools\net461\any\ef.exe` directly throws error that `System.Runtime version=6.0.0.0` could not be found despite .net6 being installed.

UPDATE:

Further investigations:

1. .net core cli requires .net core sdk to be installed.
2. tried using `dotnet ef migrations script` on build server as a workaround. That command tries to connect the database which means that build server needs direct access to database.
3. `dotnet ef` does not connect to database as current user but uses the machine account.

Comment: Did you try [the command-line tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet): `dotnet ef database update`

Comment: Net461 seems like the wrong folder

Comment: Yes tried the cli but it requires sdk to be installed. Updated question with further investigations.

Comment: Is there any official documentation on how to deploy ef to production environments?